# How to Poll an Active MQ for only 10 minutes?

Tags: timer, activemq-classic, polling, timertask

I am using Active MQ for messaging queue. My requirement is to Poll the queue for 10 minutes, read all the messages coming meanwhile, write them in a file, save it and then again read the queue for another 10 minutes and so on. 
PFB the code,

```
switch(waitIntervalSec) {
            case 0:
                // Wait indefinitely for a message
                msg = consumer.receive();
                break;
            case -1:
                // Don't wait at all.   
                msg = consumer.receiveNoWait();
                break;
            default:
                // Wait up to the specified amount of time for a msg
                msg = consumer.receive(waitIntervalSec);
                break;
        }
```

But I do not see polling effect, the debugger is not waiting at "msg = consumer.receive(waitIntervalSec);" this line for 10 minutes. I guess that is because as soon as it reads first message, the consumer breaks..is it so?

So I have other code in mind,

```
  Integer endTimeInMiliSec = currentTimeInMiliSec + 10000; //add 10 minutes

  while(currentTimeInMiliSec < endTimeInMiliSec){ 
          msg = consumer.receive();
  }
```

How can I improve this code? Is it accurate and safe to assume that it will work?

share your inputs plz.

Answer (score 0):

`receive` with a timeout waits for one message or until time is up.

It's a good idea to have some, but not infinite, waiting time in a receive call inside a loop.

So, your second code could work, but poll for some time, like a few seconds, then collect all polled messages, write the file and continue the loop.